# C++ Best practice pattern of using polymorphic data member

Tags: c++, oop

What is the best practice pattern of using polymorphic data member in C++?
The simplest one that I know is just using a plain pointer.

For example, if the type of data member is not polymorphic:

```
class Fruit {
  public:
    int GetWeight() { return 1; }
};

class Food {
  public:
    Food(Fruit f=Fruit()) : m_fruit(f) {}
    void SetFruit(Fruit f) { m_fruit = f; }
    Fruit GetFruit() { return m_fruit; }
    int Test() { return m_fruit.GetWeight(); }
  private:
    Fruit m_fruit;
};
// Use the Food and Fruit classes
Food food1; //global scope
void SomeFunction() {
  Fruit f;
  food1.SetFruit(f);
}
int main() {
  Fruit fruit1, fruit2;
  Food food2(fruit1);
  food2.SetFruit(fruit2);
  food2.SetFruit(Fruit());
  SomeFunction();
  food1.Test();
  food2.Test();
  return 0;
}
```

It is easy to use the classes in many ways with minimum possibility for errors.

Now if we make Fruit a base class (use polymorphic), this is the simplest/best one I can think of:

```
class Fruit {
  public:
    virtual int GetWeight() { return 0; }
};

class Apple : public Fruit {
  public:
    virtual int GetWeight() { return 2; }
};

class Banana : public Fruit {
  public:
    virtual int GetWeight() { return 3; }
};

class Food {
  public:
    Food(Fruit& f=defaultFruit) : m_fruit(&f) {}
    void SetFruit(Fruit& f) { m_fruit = &f; }
    Fruit& GetFruit() { return *m_fruit; }
    int Test() { return m_fruit->GetWeight(); }
  private:
    Fruit* m_fruit;
    static const Fruit m_defaultFruit = Fruit();
};
// Use the Food and Fruit classes
Food food1; //global scope
void SomeFunction() {
  Apple a;
  food1.SetFruit(a);
}

int main() {
  Apple a;
  Banana b;
  Food food2(a);
  food2.SetFruit(b);
  food2.SetFruit(Apple()); //Invalid ?!
  SomeFunction(); //Weakness: the food1.m_fruit points to invalid object now.
  food1.Test();   //Can the compiler detect this error? Or, can we do something to assert m_fruit in Food::Test()?
  food2.Test();
  return 0;
}
```

Is there any better way of doing this? I try to keep it simple not using any new/delete statement. (Note: must be able to have default value)

**UPDATE:**
Lets consider a more practical example:

```
class Personality {
public:
  void Action();
};
class Extrovert : public Personality {
  ..implementation..
};
class Introvert : public Personality {
  ..implementation..
};

class Person {
  ...
  void DoSomeAction() { personality->Action(); }
  ...
  Personality* m_personality;
};
```

The aim is to have persons with different personalities, and to make it easy to add more Personality by subclassing. What is the best way to implement this? Since logically, we only need one object for each type of Personality, it does not make much sense for a Person to copy or assume ownership of Personality object. Could there be any difference approach/design that does not require us to deal with copy/ownership problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you're better off with separate default and copy constructors.  Also, you shouldn't take the address of something passed in by reference; it could be an object on the stack that will go away soon. In the case of your function:

```
void SomeFunction() {
  Apple a;
  food1.SetFruit(a);
}
```

`a` (and thus `&a` as well) becomes invalid when the function returns, so `food1` would contain an invalid pointer.

Since you're storing a pointer, you should expect the `Food` to assume ownership of the passed-in `Fruit`.

```
class Food {
  public:
    Food() : m_fruit(new Fruit()) {}
    Food(Fruit* f) : m_fruit(f) {}
    void SetFruit(Fruit* f) { if(m_fruit != f) { delete m_fruit; m_fruit = f; } }
    Fruit& GetFruit() { return *m_fruit; }
    const Fruit& GetFruit() const { return *m_fruit; }
    int Test() { return m_fruit->GetWeight(); }
  private:
    Fruit* m_fruit;
};
```

The other option is for `Food`to make a copy of the `Fruit` it is passed.  This is tricky.  In the old days, we would define a `Fruit::clone()` method which subclasses would override:

```
class Fruit {
  public:
    virtual int GetWeight() { return 0; }
    virtual Fruit* clone() const { return new Fruit(*this); }
};

class Apple : public Fruit {
  public:
    virtual int GetWeight() { return 2; }
    virtual Fruit* clone() const { return new Apple(*this); }
};

class Banana : public Fruit {
  public:
    virtual int GetWeight() { return 3; }
    virtual Fruit* clone() const { return new Banana(*this); }
};
```

I don't think you can make a virtual constructor in the way you'd need to make this prettier.

Then the `Food` class changes to:

```
class Food {
  public:
    Food() : m_fruit(new Fruit()) {}
    Food(const Fruit& f) : m_fruit(f.clone()) {}
    void SetFruit(const Fruit& f) { delete m_fruit; m_fruit = f.clone(); }
    Fruit& GetFruit() { return *m_fruit; }
    const Fruit& GetFruit() const { return *m_fruit; }
    int Test() { return m_fruit->GetWeight(); }
  private:
    Fruit* m_fruit;
};
```

With this setup, your `SomeFunction` would work since `food1` no longer depends on `a`'s existence.

Comment: +1 Nice, clear write-up.  You can use the co-variant return type leniency to have derived object's clone function return pointers to the derived types... just preserves a little more of the compiler's type knowledge, better documents what's happening, and avoids a cast sometimes.

Comment: The weakness of passing the ownership of the passed-in `Fruit` is that we cannot assign the same object many times. For example, we have `Apple* a = new Apple(some parameters);` and we want to do `Food f1(a);`, `Food f2(a);`, and so on. So, does that mean the "make a copy" strategy is better?

Comment: @Tony: Would you mind to give me an example for that? Maybe posted as a new answer?

Comment: @leiiv: not worth another answer, just a tiny change to the return types as in `virtual Banana* clone() const { return new Banana(*this); }`.  Re "assigning many times", yes - copying fixes that problem, and is safer.  But, copying big objects can be slow, so smart-pointers using reference-counters (see boost shared_ptr) can automate the process, but note then that any modifications to the fruit's state will be seen through both Food's pointers.

Comment: @Tony: Thanks, I just realize what you meant. The weakness of "defensive copying" is the performance overhead. We can use "copy-on-write" strategy, but it makes things even more complicated. So it seems that there is no "holy grail" for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a clean and simple way to do it without operator new, because the different objects may take up different amount of space in memory. So Food can't contain a Fruit itself, but only a pointer to Fruit, which in turn would have to be allocated on the heap. So here are some alternatives.

Take a look at the library [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/any.html#id1010145). It exists precisely to solve your problem. The down side is that it adds a lot of Boost dependencies, and while it may make your code look simple, it would be harder to understand for anyone not familiar with the library. Underneath, of course, it still does new/delete.

To do those manually, you can make Food accept a pointer to Fruit, and take ownership of it by calling delete in its destructor `~Food()` (or it can use a smart pointer like shared_ptr, scoped_ptr, or auto_ptr, to have it deleted automatically). You'd have to clearly document that the passed in value MUST be allocated with new. (The default value will present a special annoyance; you'd have to either check for it, or add a flag, or allocate a copy of that value with `operator new` as well.)

You may want to be able to take any Fruit as argument and make a copy of it on the heap. That takes more work because you don't know, when making the copy, which Fruit it actually is. One common way to solve it involves adding a virtual method clone() to the Fruit, which derived Fruits have to implement appropriately.

Comment: I realized that I basically just described in words Mike DeSimone's solution (posted at the same time). That just goes to show that this is indeed the usual way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Your `SetFruit()` is assigning `f`'s address to `m_fruit`, not the address of whatever was passed in. Since `f` is just a function argument, it exists on the stack only until `SetFruit()` returns. After that, `f` goes away and its address is no longer valid. Thus, `m_fruit` is pointing to something that doesn't exist.

So instead, do something like this:

```
class Food {
  public:
    Food(Fruit* f = &defaultFruit) : m_fruit(f) {}
    void SetFruit(Fruit* f) { m_fruit = f; }
    Fruit* GetFruit() { return m_fruit; }
    int Test() { return m_fruit->GetWeight(); }
  private:
    Fruit* m_fruit;
    static const Fruit m_defaultFruit;
};
```

Polymorphism requires that you do everything with *pointers* (or references as certain parameters, but that doesn't apply to your case).

Comment: SetFruit(Fruit& f), f is just a reference to the passed object, so I think &f will give the address of whatever object passed. Are you sure about this?

Comment: @leiiv Feel free to cout both &f and &a if you are skeptical.

Comment: I just tried it using a simple test, and it gave me the same address.

Comment: Passing in an object by reference does *not* make a local copy the way passing by value does.  At the machine code level, passing an object by reference and passing a pointer by value are the same thing, and for this reason Objective-C doesn't use references, only pointers.  The main semantic differences between pointers and references is that a pointer can be NULL (i.e. `0` can be implicitly cast to any pointer type) and a reference cannot (since it can only be created from an existing object), and pointer variables can be changed while references cannot.

Comment: And, yes, I am aware that you can manufacture a "null reference" through explicit typecast (e.g. `Fruit& nullFruit = *(Fruit*)0);`), but you can subvert a lot of other rules with explicit typecasts and break your program (e.g. `Food food; Fruit* fruitInFood = *(Fruit**)&food;` which may "look right" but has no guarantee of working).